# Clay drain pipe repair

Tags: repair, drain, pipe, replacement

I was digging up a foundation and broke some parts of the top sewer pipe. The pipe is encased in concrete so not easy to replace. How can we repair the hole without replacing the pipe?

Comment: Picture would really help.  Can't really repair clay... but maybe alternatives could be found.